# Generating Uniformly Distributed Pseudo-random Numbers in C++

Tags: c++, random

In [cplusplus.com reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) it's stated that, using modulo operator when trying to generate random numbers will make lower numbers more likely:

```
random_var = rand() % 100 + 1; //this will generate numbers between 1-100
```

Why are lower numbers more likely? And if they're, why aren't we using this code below :

```
random_var = rand()/(RAND_MAX/100) + 1; //also will generate those, more uniform I guess
```

Comment: I explained a little about that [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7114482/596781).

Comment: The easiest replacement is to just use `<random>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say RAND_MAX is 150. (Obviously it's not actually.) And we want numbers from 0-99. Then we do `rand() % 100`. Cool.

The problem is, what if RAND() returns a number greater than 100? Let's take 102. `102 % 100 = 2`, and `2 % 100 = 2`. So there is a `2/150` chance that we will get a 2 with the given algorithm. But a number above 50? There's only a `1/150` chance that we'll get it. The higher RAND_MAX, the less of a problem this is, but it remains an issue.

Notice that if RAND_MAX were divisible by the number that you wanted to "modulate" it by, all numbers would be equally likely. i.e if RAND_MAX were 200 rather than 150. Hope this helps!

Edit: the actual math.

RAND_MAX is guaranteed to be at least 32767. If we want a range from 0-99, we can do `RAND() % 100`. Then, numbers between 0 and 67 will all appear 328 possible times, while 68-99 will appear only 327 times each. That's a 1.0010071% chance for the first 68 numbers, and only a 0.9979553% chance for the rest of them. We want them all to be 1%! Usually not a major issue, but depending on the use case, could show some strange behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now, what if we used a float division for rand()/(RAND_MAX/100) in the second case. Would that solve the problem?

Comment: I haven't run a simulation or done out the math, but I'm pretty sure that second method is correct. I think it might have some somewhat funky behavior due to the nature of floats, and will be a little slower, but It looks like it will be a flatter distribution. If I'm wrong, someone correct me!

Comment: (You would want a floor of the float division, obviously, in the second method.)