# c++ create a random decimal between 0.1 and 10

Tags: c++, random

How would I do this?

This is my attempt of doing so:

```
srand (time(NULL));
seed = ((double)rand()) / ((double)RAND_MAX) * 10 + 0.5;
```

Also what is the way of creating a random **integer** between 0 and some int x. [0,x]

Comment: What distribution do you want to achieve? Uniform?

Comment: Just create a random decimal from `0` to `9.9` and add `0.1`...

Comment: See the edit to my answer for your integer question.

Answer (score 12):

The C++11 way:

```
#include <random>

std::random_device rd;
std::default_random_engine generator(rd()); // rd() provides a random seed
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0.1,10);

double number = distribution(generator);
```

If you only want integers, use this distribution instead:

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, x);
```

C++11 is really powerful and well-designed in this respect. The generators are separate from the choice of distribution, ranges are taken into account, thread safe, performance is good, and people spent a lot of time to make sure it's all correct. That last part is harder to get right than you think.

Comment: More information at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114043/random-number-generation-in-c11-how-to-generate-how-do-they-work

Comment: @Silex good link with a longer overview. This talk from GoingNative 2013 is also very interesting and informative: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Answer (score 2):

```
srand (time(NULL));
seed = ((double)rand()) / ((double)RAND_MAX) * 9.9 + 0.1;
```

To show up to 2 decimal places:

```
printf("%.2lf\n", seed);
```

If the `x` you need is smaller than `RAND_MAX`, then use

```
seed = rand() % (x+1);
```

to generate an integer in `[0, x]`.

Comment: Is there any way that I can format it so that only up to two decimal places show up?

Comment: To show only two decimal, control how you print it to the screen. For example, `sprintf("%.2d", float_number);`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

float r(int fanwei)
{
    srand( (unsigned)time(NULL) ); 
    int nTmp =  rand()%fanwei;
    return (float) nTmp / 10;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout<<r(100)<<endl; 
    return 0;
}
```