# Decimal Generate Random Number within a range including negatives?

Tags: c++, random, dynamically-generated

I have the below function to generate a random number within a `min, max` range:

```
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */

//..

int GenerateRandom(int min, int max) //range : [min, max)
{
    static bool first = true;
    if (first)
    {
        srand(time(NULL)); //seeding for the first time only!
        first = false;
    }

    return min + rand() % (max - min); // returns a random int between the specified range
}
```

I want to include [c++ create a random decimal between 0.1 and 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19652657/c-create-a-random-decimal-between-0-1-and-10) functionality or/and [create a random decimal number between two other numbers](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/26963/) functionality into the above function **without** excluding negatives. So I want to get the decimal between "any" range: `[negative, negative]`, `[negative, positive]` and `[positive, positive]`

Comment: Could you incorporate the information in the links into the post itself?

Comment: Hey @kaveish, the functionality is summarized by the title of those links. Both are within positive range. I wanted to keep it clean here but I will include it. Thanks

Comment: The `c++11` method [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19652723/1885037) works for both positive and negative decimals.

Comment: @kav my `std:: namespace` didn't recognize the codes so I dropped and looked for next else. Do you know why?

Comment: I would need more information, but make sure you compile with the `-std=c++11` flag if using `gcc`.

Comment: Be aware that computers work in binary, not decimal. You can't actually generate `0.1` as that's an infinitely long binary number.

Comment: @ms so if I do that more frequent it will consume a lot of processing power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make sure that `min`, `max` are ordered correctly, and use floating point rather than integers, e.g.

```
double GenerateRandom(double min, double max)
{
    static bool first = true;
    if (first)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        first = false;
    }
    if (min > max)
    {
        std::swap(min, max);
    }
    return min + (double)rand() * (max - min) / (double)RAND_MAX;
}
```

<kbd>[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/WOy3c8)</kbd>

Comment: Hey Paul. But I want a decimal though

Comment: Like a boss. Thank you. It gave me hard time to figure it out !! (without a lunch yet maybe?) cu