# Rolling dice for an array

Tags: c++, arrays

What I need this program to do is roll 36000 2d6, output the results of each value and how often it occurs in a table format. Unfortunately I'm unfamiliar with how arrays work. This is what I have so far:

```
int DiceArray()
{
    int rollOne = 0;
    int rollTwo = 0;
    int countrolls = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for (countrolls=1; countrolls<=36000; countrolls++)
    {
        rollOne = (rand() % 6) + 1;
        rollTwo = (rand() % 6) + 1;
        sum = rollOne+rollTwo;
    }
}
```

So, I need an array for the dice results which I'm guessing is gonna look like result[11] because it lists 2 through 12 for the sum of the dice. Then I'm gonna have to make the array multidimensional; I'll need a second column for the results.

So, for instance, the result of two would occur we'll say 700 times. So I'd need something like outcome[2]. Is that right? And how would I get the right values for my array, anyways?

I suppose for the result array I just list them like so since they'll always be the same: {2, 3, 4,... 12}

But how do I output my sum to array?

Comment: Declaring an array, would be a good start. :-)

Comment: If you have a C++11 compliant compiler, please do not use rand(): http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3924.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure, what you're asking, but it seems like you need a simple [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram). Like this:

```
void DiceArray()
{
  int rollOne = 0;
  int rollTwo = 0;
  int sum = 0;

  // This array holds histogram. hist[0] and hist[1] are always zero.
  int hist[13] = { 0 }; 

  for (int countrolls = 0; countrolls < 36000; ++countrolls)
  {
    rollOne = (rand() % 6) + 1;
    rollTwo = (rand() % 6) + 1;
    sum = rollOne+rollTwo;
    hist[sum]++;
  }

  for (int i = 2; i <= 12; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << i << ": " << hist[i] << std::endl;
  }
}
```

This function prints the following:

```
2: 949
3: 1974
4: 2898
5: 3987
6: 5133
7: 6088
8: 4944
9: 3976
10: 3075
11: 1991
12: 985
```

Comment: @Vincent if `RAND_MAX` is `2^31-1` that contributes an over selection of 1 in 2 billion to `1` over `2` through `6`.  Detecting that reliably would take on the order of the order of `10^18` trials (double order of is not a typo -- the `10^18` is a napkin estimate based off a statistical rule of thumb).  The tendency for `rand()` to be a poor RNG will contribute **much much** more towards inhomogenuity (how do you spell that word?) -- `rand()` often is a pretty crappy RNG.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <array>

std::array<std::size_t, 13> DiceArray(const std::size_t count)
{
    std::random_device device;
    std::mt19937 engine(device());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> distribution(1, 6);
    std::array<std::size_t, 13> result = {};
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        ++result[distribution(engine)+distribution(engine)];
    }
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   auto result = DiceArray(36000);
   for (std::size_t i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i) {
       std::cout<<i<<" "<<result[i]<<std::endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of `result[11];` would work. You would have to zero-initialize it too.

```
int result[11] = {0};
```

Keep in mind that arrays are zero-based. So this array would cover the range of 0-10. You can work with that by subtracting off the minimum dice roll. Increment the corresponding array location for each roll in your loop:

```
++result[sum-2];
```

Accessing the value again requires subtracting the minimum dice roll:

```
int numTwos = result[2-2];
int numTens = result[10-2];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a C++11 answer.  Based off [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114043/random-number-generation-in-c11-how-to-generate-how-do-they-work)

```
 typedef std::mt19937 MyRNG;  // the Mersenne Twister with a popular choice of parameters

 std::vector< unsigned > DiceArray(
   unsigned how_many_rolls, unsigned dice_count,
   MyRNG& rng
 )
 {
   // d6!
   std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t> d6(1,6);
   std::vector< unsigned > retval;
   retval.resize( dice_count * 6+1 );
   for (unsigned count = 0; count < how_many_rolls; ++count)
   {
     unsigned sum = 0;
     for(unsigned i = 0; i < dice_count; ++i) {
       sum += d6(rng);
     }
     retval[sum] += 1;
   }
   return retval;
 }
```

And next we use it:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  MyRNG rng;
  uint32_t seed_val = 0;       // populate somehow -- as `0` it will replicate the same sequence each time.  A common trick is to grab the current time or some other source of entropy
  rng.seed(seed_val); // avoid calling this more than once per experiment.  It resets the RNG, if you call it again it will repeat the same sequence of numbers as the first time.
  std::vector<unsigned> result = DiceArray(36000, 2, rng);
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i) {
     std::cout << i <<": " << result[i] << "\n";
  }
}
```