# The behavior of rand() within a loop condition

Tags: c++, loops, random, iteration

I am trying to better understand the behavior of a loop containing some sort of a rand() as its end condition. Consider the following example:

```
for(int i=0; i < rand()%6+10; i++) { do something }
```

In this case, the loop will iterate between 10 to 15 times.
My question is: Will the termination value be evaluated once and then reused for the rest of the iterations? or will it be re-evaluated with each iteration?

In addition, is this considered bad practice?

Comment: It cannot possibly be considered "bad practice" without knowing your intent. Whether it is a "bad practice" depends on what you wanted this code to do. The loop condition is evaluated on each iteration in its entirety. If that's what you need, then your code is perfectly fine. The code would make no sense if the expression to the right of `<` always evaluated to the same value. But `rand()` does not evaluate to the same value, which means that the above code is not meaningless. If you indeed *want* to re-generate the completion condition at each iteration, then the code is perfectly fine.

Comment: Consider `for (int i = 0, i_end = blah; i != i_end; i++)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition is evaluated fully before each iteration.  (Think about it: how would the compiler know which parts you want evaluated each time, and which parts you don't?)

Whether or not it is bad practice depends on the situation.  In cases where the termination condition may change during the loop, it makes sense.  If you want to loop a random number of times then you should pre-evaluate the termination value, or you will wind up with a different random distribution than you think you have.

If you evaluate `rand()` on each iteration then the odds of the termination condition being met would change each iteration depending on the value of `i`, and you would find some terminating values of `i` over-represented compared to a uniform distribution.  Having said that, in your case the distribution wouldn't be uniform anyway, even if you evaluated it ahead of time, because (1) `rand()` is not guaranteed to produce values with uniform distribution to my knowledge, and (2) taking the modulus of a random function where the range is not evenly divisible by the modulus will skew the distribution. The larger the range of the random function the less the skew will be given a particular modulus, but it will still be present.

Comment: _(Think about it: how would the compiler know which parts you want evaluated each time, and which parts you don't?)_: Well, `int i=0;` is not executed with each iteration, but `i++;` is. Therefore, I was wondering if the condition is executed once, like the initialization, or repeatedly, just as the incrimination does.

But you definitely answered my question, and for that I am thankful :)

Comment: @Gil Well it says so in the standard. See 6.5.3: `[ Note: Thus the first statement specifies initialization for the loop; the condition (6.4) specifies a test, made before each iteration, [...]`

Comment: @remyabel Where can I see this standard?

Comment: @GilDekel: On the [isocpp.org](http://isocpp.org/) site, look to the top-left and there is a link to a working draft of the standard.

Comment: @cdhowie: Assuming uniform distribution from `rand() % 6`, the probabilities of completion at each value of `i` in range `[10..15]` are as follows: `0.1(6)`, `0.2(7)`, `0.2(7)`, `0.(185)`, `0.07716049...`, `0.0115432...`. Which means that the most probable final values of `i` are `11` and `12`. Therefore your assertion that the loop will exit with fewer iterations more frequently is not entirely accurate: the final value of `10` will occur less frequently than `11` or `12`.

Comment: ... and `11` and `12` will occur with the same average frequency.

Comment: Moreover (I missed it at the first sight), the final value of `13` will also occur slightly more frequently than the final value of `10`.

Comment: @AndreyT This is a bit surprising, and I guess I should have experimented first. What is intuitive seems to be wrong in this case. I [ran a trial](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ItofffaHI08-hV-ksje31_9zuBwgPQtWW_XIRuDVZCk/pubchart?oid=1067530630&format=interactive) with 1,000,000 executions and using `i < rand()%50+10` as the terminating condition. The results appear to indicate a Poisson distribution, though I admit I am dabbling in territory I'm not extremely educated on. I have removed the part of my answer that made this inaccurate claim.

Comment: @cdhowie: It would be a classic Poisson if the probability of termination on each separate iteration was constant. If you replace the termination condition with, say, `0 == rand() % 6`, it would become a classic Poisson (on each independent iteration the chance of termination is the same `1/6`). But in case of `i < rand() % 6 + 10` the probability of termination of each further iteration *grows* (`1/6`, `2/6`. `3/6` and so on to `6/6` for the `i == 15`). This makes it different.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard says that the `for` statement:

`for ( for-init-statement conditionopt ; expressionopt ) statement`

is equivalent to:

`{
    for-init-statement
    while ( condition) {
          statement
          expression ;
    }
}`

> [ Note: Thus the first statement specifies initialization for the
>   loop; the condition (6.4) specifies a test, made before each
>   iteration, [...]

So yes, the condition will be re-evaluated with each iteration.

As for whether or not using `rand()` is bad practice... the `rand()` function is library and platform dependent. On linux, you can find documentation by doing `man 3 rand`. For example, the [online man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand) says:

> Do not use this function in applications intended to be portable when
>   good randomness is needed.

And [cppreference's opinion on std::rand](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand):

> There are no guarantees as to the quality of the random sequence
>   produced. In the past, some implementations of `rand()` have had
>   serious shortcomings in the randomness, distribution and period of the
>   sequence produced (in one well-known example, the low-order bit simply
>   alternated between 1 and 0 between calls).
>
> rand() is not recommended for serious random-number generation needs,
>   like cryptography. It is recommended to use C++11's [random number
>   generation
>   facilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) to
>   replace `rand()`. <sub>(since C++11)</sub>

If you want a solid introduction on how to use these C++11 features, consult [Random number generation in C++11, how to generate, how do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114043/random-number-generation-in-c11-how-to-generate-how-do-they-work).

For an analysis on various usages of `rand()` and why they're bad, see [Julienne Walker's article](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx).

For example:

> ```
> 1 int r = rand() % N;
> ```
>
> To instead add a lower bound and set the range to [M..N), one might do
>   this:
>
> ```
> 1 int r = M + rand() % ( N - M );
> ```
>
> Anyone who does this will be rewarded with a seemingly random sequence
>   and be thrilled that their clever solution worked. Unfotunately, this
>   does not work. The first solution only works when N evenly divides
>   into RAND_MAX. The second solution isn't any better. The reason is
>   because forcing the range in this way eliminates any chance of having
>   a uniform distribution. Now, this is okay if you care nothing about
>   some numbers being more probable than others, but to be correct, you
>   must work with the distribution instead of destroy it.

Comment: The C++ standard is not completely correct regarding the equivalency at the top of your answer, particularly when it comes to how `continue;` behaves.

Comment: Thank you for the awesome references!