# srand() + rand() with local scope

Tags: c++, c++11, random, scope, thread-safety

I have a function that calls *srand* and *rand* like this:

```
void foo() {
   int seed = some_operation();
   std::srand(seed);
   int value = std::rand();
   // Do something with random value
}
```

However, I don't want to change the global state of *rand*. Whats the easiest way to get a random number then?

Requirements:

- random number must be deterministic based on seed
- C++11 is fine
- foo should be thread safe
- the global state of rand should not be modified

**Edit:**

There is a stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665818/best-way-to-generate-random-numbers-using-c11-random-library) asking how to generate random numbers. The accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19666713/369009) however shows how to generate truly unique random numbers, using a slow *std::random_device*. I just needed a simple generator using a fixed seed instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to generate random numbers using c++11 random library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665818/best-way-to-generate-random-numbers-using-c11-random-library)

Comment: Also [Random number generation in C++11 , how to generate , how do they work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7114043)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> C++11 is fine

Then use the new [pseudorandom number library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random):

```
#include <random>

int foo() {
    int seed = some_operation();
    std::minstd_rand rand(seed);
    int value = rand();
    // Do something with random value
}
```

`minstd_rand` is a simple linear congruential engine, similar to that typically used by `std::rand()`, but with its state encapsulated in a class. Other engines are available, if you need a higher quality pseudorandom sequence. The Mersenne Twister, `std::mt19937`, is usually a good choice if you don't have specific requirements.

Comment: @Brahim: To protect what? The engine is a local variable, so can only be accessed by the thread that's calling the function.

Comment: You are right. I just thought that the library functon's thread-safety may be undefined.

Answer (score 2):

[`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) defines a number of PRNG classes that you can use, which do not use global states.

For example, using a default Mersenne Twister, [`std::mt19937`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
  int seed = 1234;
  std::mt19937 rng(seed);
  std::cout << "Random number: " << rng() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to provide your own implementation, with its own seed data.  A template for doing that is provided in the [manpage for rand()](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man3/rand.3.html).

```
static unsigned long next = 1;

/* RAND_MAX assumed to be 32767 */
int myrand(void) {
    next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
    return((unsigned)(next/65536) % 32768);
}

void mysrand(unsigned seed) {
    next = seed;
}
```

Comment: He asked for a solution with no global state, and you post an answer with global state.

Comment: @DanielKO: Actually, he said he didn't want to change *the* global state of `rand()`, which this does not.  I get your point, however, and was kind of expecting that someone could modify this to manage the state in a way that suited their purposes -- for example if they wanted one seed per thread, that would require custom logic which isn't addressed in any of the answers.

Comment: Note: The above code was copied verbatim from the man page.  It is really only an example of how you might generate a predictable random number sequence in a very portable way (and with custom state data).  Approaches using `<random>` are likely better if you are targeting C++11 specifically.  The code, as written, is not thread-safe.  To achieve thread-safety you need to manage the state variable `next` in a way that matches your thread safety strategy.