# Peudorandom numbers in c++ not random enough

Tags: c++, random, numbers

I am a new coder and tried a random numbers generator. After 1h it worked and i tried printing lots of random numbers. My header:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>

int Randomnumber(int Min, int Max)
{
    int RanID;
    srand(time(0));
    RanID = rand();
    RanID = (RanID % Max - 1) + Min;

    return RanID;
}
```

My main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdio>
#include "Random.h"

int Max;
int Min;

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                std::cout << Randomnumber(2, 200);
            }
            std::cout << "" << std::endl;
        }
    std::cout << "Press any Key to close this application" << std::endl;
    std::system("pause");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting a wild mix of numbers 2-200 but i didn't get good results:

```
94949494949494949494
94949494949494949494
94949494949494949494
94949494949494949494
94949494949494949494
94949494949494949494
94949494949494949494
94949494949494949494
94949494949494949494
94949494949494949494
94949494949494949898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898989898989898
98989898
98989898989
```

Comment: You should call `srand` only once. Also better use the more modern C++ classes from `<random>` header. See more e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114043/random-number-generation-in-c11-how-to-generate-how-does-it-work.

Comment: You're re-seeding the generator every time you call `Randomnumber`, with `time()`,which typically only changes once per second, so two calls in the same second will always give identical results. You typically want to call `srand` only once per execution of the program. Using `%` to get the result into a range will usually produce skewed results, but that's quite  minor compared to the other problem.

Comment: Note for C++ have a look at this documentation (you are using the "C" variant): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random. The C++ random generators are better (can even use entropy devices) and have distributions you can control.  (rand()%some_value) may be good enough, but the modulo operator will (slightly) skew your distribution as well. The last thing you should do is reinitalize your seed over and over again, and time is a notoriously bad source (it can even be predictable and reverse engineered)

Comment: Despite the tone of the comments, there's nothing wrong with using `rand()` for quick-and-dirty random number generation. Just remember to only call `stand` once.

Comment: @PeteBecker The rand() method is indeed often good enough but the way it is seeded usually is not :) And lots of people don't learn about the <random> header at all in their initial C++ training so for me it is more about pointing out it exists.

Comment: You'll never notice the skew that you'll get from using `%` to generate values in the range [2..200]. Don't worry about that until you get things working and then, **if** it's a problem, you can look into other approaches and the problems that they introduce.

Comment: @Aconcagua -- that doesn't work. It just distributes the more common values differently. To eliminate skew you have to discard values.

Comment: @PeteBecker Could you explain further? Your statement seems to imply that you cannot rely on the RNG to equally distribute values over the range of [0; RAND_MAX].

Comment: @Aconcagua -- it's just counting. Imagine a generator that produces values uniformly distributed in the range [0..6], and you want numbers uniformly distributed in the range [0..5]. Using `%`, clearly, generates twice as many 0's as any other digit. Multiply by 5 and divide by 6 runs into a similar problem. It maps 0->0, 1->0, 2->1, 3->2, 4->3, 5->4, and 6->5. So 0 still comes up twice as often. Try some other examples. The problem is that it's trying to map 6 digits into 5 slots, and there's no way to get the same number of digits into each slot. The same thing happens with larger ranges.

Comment: @Aconcagua -- the solution is to discard values. Whenever the [0..6] generator produces 6 you ignore it and try again. For a generator with a larger range you discard anything greater than or equal to `(RAND_MAX / range) * range` (if I remember correctly; there might be a `+ 1` in there somewhere.).